# CSplain support for English quotes

Tags: plain-tex, csplain

In CSplain, there is a lot of multi-language support (including UTF-8 input in 8-bit TeX engines) but one curiously missing thing was support for UTF-8 English quote glyphs.  From reading the CSplain source, I've figured that the following lines add support:

```
% Assuming T1/Cork encoding
\input t1code % this set of macros is provided by CSplain

% The following lines add the "missing" support for English quotes
\chardef \elq 96
\chardef \erq 39

\mubyte\erqq ^^e2^^80^^9d\endmubyte % English right double quote
\mubyte\elq  ^^e2^^80^^98\endmubyte % English left single quote
\mubyte\erq  ^^e2^^80^^99\endmubyte % English right single quote
```

(The above is needed when the source file is encoded in UTF-8 but one is using an 8-bit TeX engine.)

Is there any reason this isn't included by default (perhaps incompatibility with other languages somehow)?
Is this the correct way to add this support?

(Additional info about CSplain was published by its author in a [TUGboat article](https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb34-1/tb106olsak-csplain.pdf))

Comment: Thank you for this notice. I'll add the missing codes included from T1 encoding to the "UTF8 to T1 convertor", i. e. to the file `t1enc-u.tex`. The codes like inverted question mark, quotes, endash etc. are generated by ligatures in CM fonts, but they are not working in `\tt` variants of these font. This is "historical complication" which is (unfortunately) inherited into IL2 encoding which is default in `csplain`. But T1 encoding doesn't have this complication. IMHO, this isn't typical question here, I am ready to say more about it via email.

Comment: acarlow, @wipet: what is the status of this question? Would it be possible to add a summary of wipet's email as an answer here? This way, the question gets answered and the knowledge can be shared with others. :-)

Comment: I'm closing this question because it's a bug report which has been processed.